# How can we be sure smashing atoms in an atom smasher does not cause harm?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

I have a question about atom smashers in accelerators. How can scientists performing these experiments be sure that by smashing atoms they will not be producing the effect of a bomb, thus potentially harm. After all, they do not know the results of the experiments, do they?

The results, as advertised on television, always, after all, seem, to be novel, and seem to comprise breakthroughs.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Just because you don't know precisely what will happen doesn't mean anything can happen.

Comment: Why the down votes? Just because you don't know what will happen is a good reason to ask.

Comment: @mmesser314 Because it's a bad question. For example, how can "scientists... be sure" of anything? No one can be sure of anything, but we have a pretty good idea because of... because of... what am I supposed to do, explain all of physics up to an including elementary particle physics. Also, BTW, if you happen to "smash" tritium together in the right way, you very well might produce a bomb... So, like, how am I supposed to answer this question?

Comment: Also, "as advertised on television" is not a great starting point for a question either. Yes, not everything on television is true. In fact, a lot of it is purposefully entertaining fiction. Are we arguing with or against fiction now?

Comment: Conservation of energy still applies.  Even if we succeeded in releasing all of the mass energy of the accelerated material in a burst, it is still only the mass energy of a few protons. That said, in (outlandish but possible) theory, something like Vacuum Decay could be triggered that would spread.

Comment: @mmesser314 I’m not a downvoter but I agree that the question seems to show very little research. There’s a bit of a pop science and distrust of science overtone to it. A better way to ask almost the same question would be to quote an article or the safety statement from CERN and ask for an easier to understand explanation or corroboration.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "atom smasher" is a science fiction word, not a mainstream physic word. the OP should at least read https://home.cern/science/accelerators/large-hadron-collider/safety-lhc and use mainstream physics language

Comment: @anna-v that's a very strange argument. OP is clearly not a physicist, so we cannot expect him to know the appropriate terminology. As long as we understand what he means, there is no issue. Take the opportunity to educate, instead of shutting people out for not already knowing.

Comment: @a20 This is not a general questions site, it is for questions with a background in main stream physics and needs a minimum of physics backround, not science fiction

Answer (score 10):

The energies of the interactions of cosmic rays from outer space in the upper layers of the atmosphere are sometimes many orders of magnitude higher than those achieved in the LHC. So if something untoward could happen from such experiments, it already would have in the sky.

The LHC operates at $\mathrm{13}$ $\mathrm{TeV}$ which is close to $2*10^{-6}$ $\mathrm{Joules}$, whereas the highest energy cosmic ray observed, the [Oh-My-God particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle) had an energy of roughly $51$ $\mathrm{Joules}$.

Comment: The center of mass energy available for particle production in a collider is 2*E (E= energy of colliding particles), whereas for a fixed target experiment (cosmic ray hitting Earth), the center of mass energy scales with $\sqrt{E}$. For the 6.8 TeV beams in the LHC (neglecting that it is not the protons that collide, putting actual collision energy lower), one would need cosmic ray particles of a factor of 1e14 larger energy. This is about a million times more than the highest energy particles observed.

Answer (score 6):

The answers given so far are greatly oversimplified. One of the theories that the LHC was designed to test was the idea that there were large extra dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_extra_dimensions . If this theory had been correct, then the LHC would have produced microscopic black holes.

A fallacious reassurance against a bad outcome from producing these black holes is that cosmic ray reactions would have already been producing them. Actually, this is wrong, because cosmic ray reactions produce products with very large recoil velocities, so black holes produced in such reactions would have flown off harmlessly (passing through the earth in the cases where that was the direction of flight). In LHC collisions, a certain fraction of collisions result in products whose velocities are low enough that they are not moving at escape velocity from the earth.

A better argument is that based on the way quantum mechanics works, we're pretty sure that if a reaction can produce black holes with a decent cross-section, then those same black holes should also decay quite fast. But this was a little risky, because there is no direct evidence that black holes obey the laws of quantum mechanics as currently formulated, and in fact there are reasons to believe that general relativity is incompatible with our current understanding of quantum mechanics.

I can't find the reference now, but there was a long paper written on this before the LHC started up. IIRC the best and most model-independent arguments were based on the fact that white dwarfs (unlike the earth) would have been destroyed by any non-decaying black holes produced by high-energy cosmic rays. I think the reasoning was quite intricate and depended somewhat on estimates of the rate at which microscopic black holes would eat various forms of matter (I guess degenerate white dwarf matter), and these estimates in turn depended on the number of extra dimensions hypothesized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate this answer. I will note that CERN has a summary:
https://home.cern/science/accelerators/large-hadron-collider/safety-lhc
which partly but not entirely supports your points here. In particular, they suggest that your point about black holes from cosmic rays immediately escaping is not necessarily true if they are charged.

Comment: That said, I would also point out that the OP does not seem to be only interested in the chances that the LHC would destroy the world/universe, but the chances that it could make some large and dangerous explosion through new physics. Presumably this is not as well constrained by astronomical observations, but I would suspect that the most relevant observational bounds are still from cosmic rays hitting Earth and nearby planets.

Answer (score 5):

To try and give a little more detail than the other answer - the energy of a single proton in an "atom smasher" like the LHC is less than the kinetic energy of a typical flying mosquito:

https://www.lhc-closer.es/taking_a_closer_look_at_lhc/0.energy

Of course, the trick is that the energy of the mosquito is distributed amoung it's $\sim 10^{23}$ other molecules, instead of focused on a single atom, like in the LHC.

In addition, the interactions that are going on during the collision are not the same kind of reactions that are going on in something like a nuclear weapon. In those weapons, some kind of cascade effect is required - roughly, each atomic decay produces *more* decays, so the effect is explosive. This is facilitated by relatively high density material (so there are more nuclei around to decay). That's the opposite thing that goes in the LHC, in which the density is very low - like 1 or several proton-proton interactions at a time.

There are in fact hypothetical dangers from these high-energy experiments. For example, since they do create high energy *density* situations, in principle things like Black Holes could form. However, since the energy is still relatively small, these black holes would be microscopic and pose no danger to the experimenters or the world:

https://angelsanddemons.web.cern.ch/faq/black-hole.html

Actually, it would be an *incredible* scientific achievement if we could produce such a quantum black hole!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other points, I would add that nature is a far more powerful particle accelerator than anything we can manage. The most energetic cosmic rays ever observed have had an energy over [a million times larger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle) than the maximum reached at the LHC. Particles with these level of energy are rare, but given that we have seen several of them over the limited time and space that we have been able to track, it is a safe bet that the Earth has been hit by many over the course of human history, we would know if they were causing anything dramatic on a macro scale.

For more information, see [this nice summary](https://home.cern/science/accelerators/large-hadron-collider/safety-lhc) by CERN themselves.

Edit: Hritik Narayan posted at the same time I was writing this with a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

The energies involved in "smashing" atoms is larger for an atom , but nothing compared with the energy of a ordinary bomb. Do zur Energie released by one fast atom is less than what you would need to heat 1mg of water 1°K.
The only possible damage is for people staying to close to the smashing, but nobody is allowed in the dangerous region

Answer (score 1):

> ...the effect of a bomb...

Are you talking about radioactive fallout?

A high-energy particle accelerator does, in fact, create some radioactivity;* but unlike a nuclear weapon, the accelerator does not explode and release the radioactivity into the environment.

Most of the radioactivity in an accelerator is immobile, trapped in the solid material comprising the accelerator and its supporting structures. Also, I have reason to believe that it is mostly short-lived—that it is safe for personnel to work near the accelerator within minutes or hours of switching it off.

---

* https://journals.aps.org/prab/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevSTAB.17.084701

Comment: Neutrons are pretty hard to make immobile in an accelerator. Had to do a lot of measurements and modeling on 14MeV neutrons and sky shine to get rad protection happy...

Comment: @JonCuster, I used to work with medical linear accelerators. Probably much lower power, and much lower energy than anything that physicists would use today, but high-enough energy (20-30 MeV) to liberate neutrons. I understand the half-life of free neutrons to be about 10 minutes, but staff at the facility waited only one minute after switching the machine off, and before entering the treatment room. Supposedly enough time for gamma radiation from the target (a living patient) to decay to insignificance. The neutrons—so they told me—all were almost immediately captured by matter in the room.